# Zapier: How to select accounts dynamically/programmatically

Tags: zapier

A lot of Zapier steps have "Choose account" as the second configuration section ("Choose app & event" --> "Choose account" --> "Set up actions" --> "Test action").

**Is there any way to select the account dynamically?** We want to be able to use the account that corresponds to conditions determined earlier in the zap (i.e. using a value from the output of a step). Right now, we have to manually select the account from the list of connected accounts, and there seems to be no way to change it during the zap.

Which means for each new account that we manage, we have to copy the entire zap just to change the selected account. And then we have an ever growing list of zaps to manage (every change needs to be repeated for every single account/zap).

Background: Our company manages a growing number of accounts -- let's use Twitter accounts as an example. We use Zapier to update these accounts (ex: send out a new tweet) based on some triggers & conditions. Imagine managing hundreds of accounts this way; it's not scalable.

And please don't tell me about Paths. That is not a scalable solution either, and it's limited to only 3 paths (it can be increased to 10, but that's no better).

We're also aware that Zapier has a limit of 2,000 app connections. That's a problem we'll deal with later.

***EDIT:*** We're also considering using an external service to update the accounts (ex: send out the new tweets), so we'd be open to suggestions in that regard. Worst case scenario, we'll build a small custom API to perform the updates on any specified account, and Zapier will call that API instead of performing the updates directly on a specific account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently possible - the params of all steps in a zap (selected account, field mappings, input field values, etc) are all locked in at zap creation time.

This is cool feedback though! Definitely worth reaching out to Zapier support about if you haven't.